# SQL select and display all values in a group that contains at least one value

Tags: sql

maybe someone has already answered this, but I'll try it here.
Say I have three columns  :

```
 **NAME**    **TEST SCORE**   **DATE**
  Chloé          67             Jan 8th 
  Dennis         98             Jan 8th
  Zakary         45             Jan 8th 
  Chloé          75             July 1st 
  Dennis         91             July 1st 
  Zakary         76             July 1st
```

And I would like to not only get the names, but also *all* the test results and dates of students having had at least one grade below 50%, so as to get something like :

```
 Zakary 45 Jan8th
 Zakary 76 July1st
```

What order could I use? I have tried having, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Really Jan8th for score 76?

Comment: Also, switch to proper date data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where name = t.name and score < 50
)
```

or:

```
select * from tablename
where name in (select name from tablename where score < 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which DB you are using, but you should try some statement like:

```
SELECT NAME, TEST_SCORE, DATE
  FROM STUDENTS
 WHERE NAME IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM STUDENTS WHERE TEST_SCORE < 50)
```

Hope it helps.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Using `join`.

```
select a.*
from tablename a
join (select distinct name from tablename where score<50) b on a.name=b.name
```